# как обновлять файлы на сервере

Tags: ftp, svn

У меня локальная копия проекта и та, которая на боевом сервере. Когда я что-то меняю в локальной копии, мне нужно применить все изменения на боевом сервере.

Сейчас использую тупо метод по FTP, то есть, грубо говоря, каждый раз копирую все файлы проекта. Подскажите пожалуйста способ, как можно нормально все это организовать.

P.S. пробовал SVN но так и не нашел материалов и статей по тому, как с нуля все это организовать. Остановился на том, что тех поддержка установила мне SVN на хостинге и на десктопе я установил клиент TortioseSVN
дальше тупик. 
Опишите пожалуйста подробнее и пошагово, как и что делать. или же ссылки на источники, где все очень подробно и понятно для новичка описано

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [post-commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) хук и напишите свой небольшой скрипт. В сети должно быть полным-полно инструкций на эту тему, ищите лучше.

Примерные шаги такие:

- Создаём рабочую копию `/trunk` вебсайта на хостинге в папке куда раньше загружались файлы по FTP. Т.е. на хостинге надо запустить команду типа `svn checkout https://svn.example.com/svn/MyWebSite/trunk`.
- Настраиваем в репозитории хук, который будет запускать [`svnlook changed`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) для анализа путей которые затронул в репозитории новая ревизия (regexp в помощь). Если коммит затронул /trunk, то необходимо запустить `svn update` на хостинге чтобы обновить рабочую копию и подтянуть изменения из репозитория.

Можно было бы всё это сделать и без анализа в /trunk идёт коммит или нет. Но с анализом лучше, т.к. если вы коммитите в другие проекты репозитория или в /branches /tags /shelves, то обновление рабочей копии не запускается. Хотя для небольшого проекта это совсем не важно.